# how to make gnuplot plot in a maximized window

Tags: windows, drawing, gnuplot

I use gnuplot from a script hundreds times a day.  I have to maximize the window every time.
Is there a way for gnuplot to make a maximized window of the plot without having to do it
manually?

Comment: What OS do you use, and which gnuplot terminal?

Comment: The question is tagged with Windows.

Comment: I think you cannot maximize the window from within gnuplot. You can either specify an explicit size like `set terminal windows size 1600,1000`, or change the `GraphSize` settings in your `wgnuplot.ini` file (see documentation of `windows` terminal), or use a hot key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409071/how-to-open-gnuplots-in-full-screen-and-a-particular-size

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and gnuplot-qt

The following command does not exactly maximize the plot window but leaves it as large as possible. Use the following command for your terminal (in my case qt) specifying the maximum screen size (in my case 959, 650). The terminal type appears when the gnuplot is initialized.

```
set terminal qt size 959, 650
```

Once the plot window is maximized, it remains maximized even if it is closed. It only fails to remain maximized if the gnuplot is closed and reopened.