# gnuplot x11 terminal - aspect ratio does not remain constant when window is resized

Tags: c++, gnuplot, aspect-ratio

I have had trouble with the aspect ratio using gnuplot on the x11 terminal.
I have tried 'set size ratio -1' and 'set size square' commands. All works well until the window is re-sized. The aspect ratio of the plot is not preserved unless the window is stretched in both directions in equal proportions.

I would like to maximize the x11 window while maintaining a square aspect ratio for the plot. Is this possible?

Also, I am using gnuplot version 4.6.5

EDIT #1:

i also have to note that im calling gnuplot from a c++ script. lets say i have an ascii file containing all the gnuplot commands called plotCOMMANDS. within my c++ script, i have the following system command to call gnuplot: `gnuplot -persist plotCOMMANDS`

if i was plotting within the gnuplot terminal, i could use the `replot` command (as suggested by Christoph). but is there a way to run the `replot` command within the c++ script each time the window is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the window content isn't updated automatically after you maximize it, but the existing plot is only rescaled to the new window size (the `windows` terminal has the same problem).

You must enter `replot` in the interactive terminal after you maximized the window. That works fine for both the `x11` and the `windows` terminals. The hotkey `e` doesn't work for `x11`. BTW: In the upcoming version 5.0 this behavior is fixed and the window automatically replots when the canvas size is changed.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Christoph. i am using a c++ script to call gnuplot and i am unsure of how to incorporate the replot command. please see my edited question

Comment: You can use `bind 'e' 'replot'` to add a hotkey. Then you only need to press `e` to have the window updated. The respective change in the sources were made on 2012-09-25, but wasn't backported to the 4.6 branch. Another option would be to use the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/q/25409071/2604213 to directly start gnuplot in fullscreen.

Comment: the `bind` solution seems to work except for one problem. im using `pause -1 'Hit return to continue: '` to keep the window interactive until the enter button is pressed. pressing 'e' does fix the scaling but the window is no longer interactive. is there anyway around this?

Comment: No, I don't know how to fix this. I've seen, that with the `wxt` the `e` hotkey works out of the box (without using `bind`) and doesn't interfere with `pause`. I tested with: `set terminal wxt; set size ratio -1; plot x; pause -1`, then changing the window size, hitting `e` and the pause is still in effect.

Comment: thats unfortunate. i do not have the wxt terminal installed. i also tried the fullscreen solution but i get the following error: `set term x11 size *0` and it points to the asterisk as the issue. the line that gnuplot does not like is `set term x11 size @monitorSize`. i have `set macros` included

Comment: Hm, seems like that `xrandr...` solution is not very flexible. How does your output line of `xrandr` look like, which shows the current screen resolution?

Comment: executing `xrandr` in the shell yields `*0   3840 x 1080   (1060mm x 301mm )  *50` as the first bit of information

Comment: No, thats the wrong line. Seems like you have a `*` in the Screen name. In my case, the relevant line showing the current resolution is `1680x1050      60.0*+`. Here, the `*` indicates the current resolution.